# Empty a QVariantList?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QVariantList. How can I empty it.

I've tried

```
myList.clear()
```

and

```
myList.empty();
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "no luck"? What did it do?

Comment: It didnt deleted it. When I added tried to add more data to it, the original data was there.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sample that shows the problem? So far I've never had issues using `clear()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QVariantList` is just a `QList<QVariant>`. So have a look at the `QList` [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html):

- [`QList::clear()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#clear): Removes all items from the list.
- [`QList::empty()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#empty): This function is provided for STL compatibility. It is equivalent to isEmpty() and returns true if the list is empty.

This makes it clear why `myList.empty();` does not work. However, `myList.clear()` should work, so probably you have a mistake somewhere else in your code.

Just to double check, add something like `qDebug() << list.length();` after the `list.clear();` line:

```
QVariantList list;
list << 42;
qDebug() << list.length();
list.clear();
qDebug() << list.length();
```

gives:

```
1
0
```